# simple rjs rails question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a extremely simple web page:

test.html.erb:

> ```
> <div id="test_div">
> Testing 1 2 3
> </div>
> ```

test.rjs:

> ```
>     page.visual_effect :highlight, "test_div"
> ```

Basically, I want my "test_div" to be highlighted when the webpage loads. But for some reason, the div doesn't highlight when I load the webpage.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

if you want javascript to execute at load time you have to put it in the header.
http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=428814